# ExpandableListView expandGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, expandablelistview

I am trying to animate the expansion and collapse of an ExpandableListView. I am targeting API level 15 so there is available a method expandGroup `(int groupPos, boolean animate)`. However it does not animate the expansion of the group. My code is below:

```
m_expandList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener(){
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)
            {
                if(m_expandList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
                {
                    m_expandList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_expandList.expandGroup(groupPosition,true);
                }
                return true; 
            }
        });
```

Below is the extract from the layout:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/ExpList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/MainLabel"   
    android:layout_above="@id/button1"     
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
```

I think that it might be a case of not using the API correctly or maybe missing something?

Also, why isn't there the same method for the collapseGroup (I mean also including the animate bool)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a bit late but the expansion animation triggers when you expand the group where the children of that group has more height than the space available.

The animation is actually the listview scrolling down to accommodate the children height. That is also the reason why there is no animation on collapse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I understand your point. I thought that the animation was actually the group expanding to reveal the children. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the listener(if you are using it just for expanding-collapsing of groups). That is already the default behavior of an `ExpandableListView` which in-fact is animated.

Comment: The only reason that I added the listener is because I was trying to make the expandablelistview animated. Even if I remove it is does not animate. I get your point and maybe you are correct. In that case, I guess I must be making another mistake but not sure what. Btw, the expandablelistview looks a bit outdated. Is it possible that this is caused by the fact that I had originally opted for minimum API level 8? But I have removed this from the manifest file and therefore should not be a problem. The list still looks like from an older version of Android (and not from 4.0.4 running on my Xoom)